# Why the array could not hold the keys of hash in the following perl script?

Tags: arrays, perl

#### hash_test.pl

```
@a=("f","a","b");
$K{"f"}{"aa"}=1;
$K{"a"}{"aa"}=1;
$k{"b"}{"bb"}=1;

foreach(@a){
@c= sort keys %{$k{$_}};
}
print "@c\n";

foreach(@c) {...}
```

```
perl hash_test.pl 
bb
```

I want to keep the keys of the hash into an array, so that I can use the array as an input for the following statements.
But it seemed that the assay `@c` just only hold the last element.

Could anyone tell me why or help me to improve the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign the array every time in the `foreach`, thus overwriting it every time. So you end up with only having the last thing assigned to it. If you move the `print` inside the `foreach` you'll see that they are all there.

To store those keys you need to add them to the array, not assign the array. I've corrected the typo `$k` to `$K`, and changed `aa` that goes with `f` to `ff` (expecting it to be a typo as well).

```
my @c;
foreach my $el (@a) {
   push @c, sort keys %{$K{$el}};
}
print "@c\n";
```

This prints the line: `ff aa bb`.  Every time through the loop all keys found in the hash for a particular array element are added to `@c`, each as a separate element. So `@c` will contain all bottom-level keys across the whole data structure.

---

However, there is more that I would like to suggest.

- *Always* `use strict;` and `use warnings;` This is not pedantry but it *directly* helps. I never write code without them.  The typo would be caught here, for example.
- Use descriptive variable names. Specifically, single-letter variable names are just too easy to confuse, unless in very short loops or where it is crystal clear what they are. (For example, a typo like this couldn't really happen.) Most importantly, the code is going to be far nicer to work with. That generally results in better code.
- Please use good indentation and spacing.  It helps a lot, in many ways.

A useful core package for nested data structures is [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), which can print the whole thing nicely formatted so we can *see* it. Try to add to the end of your code

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%K);
```

There are yet others that do the same or similar.

---

Here is another way to do what you ask.

```
my @lowest_keys = map { sort keys %{$K{$_}} } @a;
```

I call them `lowest_keys` to emphasize that these are the ones from the last hash in your data structure, the bottom of it. The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) applies processing in the block `{ ... }` to each element of `@a` in turn, returning a list with all these results. (If any one result itself is a *list*, with more elements than one, it gets merged into the overall output list. So this may create the output list with many more elements than the input.)  This *list* can then be assigned to an array, as above, or passed on to another function that expects a list as input, or interated over.

The `map` is generally used to transform an array into another, by doing to each element what is in `{ ... }` block.  Its close cousin  [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is used to *filter*, so passing through only the elements of the input list for which the condition in `{ ... }` evaluates to true, forming the output list. For example, filter out undefined array elements: `my @good = grep { defined } @all`

Answer (score 3):

Variable names are case sensitive, so %K... and %k... are not the same.
Always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and declare your variables with `my`. That prevents you from making this kind of mistakes.